# DD/MM/YYYY Date format in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

How can i change the current date to this format(DD/MM/YYYY) using moment.js?

I have tried below code.

```
$scope.SearchDate = moment(new Date(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

But it's return `0037-11-24T18:30:00.000Z`. Did't help to format current date.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You need to call [format()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) function to get the formatted value

```
$scope.SearchDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
//or $scope.SearchDate = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```

The syntax you have used is used to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) a given string to date object by using the specified formate

Comment: ok. the `new Date()` is javascript code. can you give me for get  current date by using moment.js?

Comment: @RameshRajendran it gives you the current date - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hrrnenf2/1/

Comment: @RameshRajendran 
`$scope.SearchDate = moment(moment.now()).format("DD/MM/YYYY")`

Comment: `moment()` is the same as `moment(new Date())`

Answer (score 49):

You can use this

```
moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

However, this returns a date string in the specified format for today, not a moment date object. Doing the following will make it a moment date object in the format you want.

```
var someDateString = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
var someDate = moment(someDateString, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Comment: I have date format in 'MM/DD/YY' and wants to convert it to 'DD/MM/YYYY'. So my doubt is how will moment know what format is it in. Suppose the date is '06/05/20'. How will moment know if it's MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me

```
var dateToFormat = "2018-05-16 12:57:13"; //TIMESTAMP

moment(dateToFormat).format("DD/MM/YYYY"); // you get "16/05/2018"
```

Answer (score 10):

This actually worked for me:

```
moment(mydate).format('L');
```

Comment: This will return MM/DD/YYYY. But in the actual question he is expecting DD/MM/YYYY format.

Answer (score 4):

for anyone who's using `react-moment`:

simply use `format` prop to your needed format:

```
const now = new Date()
<Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{now}</Moment>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A safe way to do this**

```
moment.locale('en-US');
moment().format("L");
```

> "06/23/2021"

```
moment.locale('fr');
moment().format("L");
```

> "23/06/2021"

Answer (score 0):

**The best way is:**

```js
let today = new Date();
let todayFormatted = moment(today).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
let startDateFormatted = moment(startDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
const isStartDateToday = (todayFormatted === startDateFormatted);
```

Comment: Except for this `startDate` thing which can be found nowhere in the question, this answer does not have anything new compared to existing answers.

Comment: I made a confusion. My solution is the best way of compare two dates is the same